# QTextCursor disappears from view while editing QTableView cell

Tags: scroll, pyqt5, qt5, qtableview, qtextedit

Here's an MRE:

```
import sys, time 
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui

start_time = time.time_ns()
def get_time():
    return '{:.3f}'.format((time.time_ns() - start_time) / 1000000000.)
 
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('MRE - cursor disappears out of view')
        self.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 100, 1000, 400))
        self.table_view = HistoryTableView(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.table_view)
        rows = [
         ['one potatoe two potatoe', 'one potatoe two potatoe'],
         ['Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque',
          'Sed ut <b>perspiciatis, unde omnis <i>iste natus</b> error sit voluptatem</i> accusantium doloremque'],
         ['Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem, quia voluptas sit, aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos, qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt, neque porro quisquam est, qui do lorem ipsum, quia dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing velit, sed quia non numquam do eius modi tempora incididunt, ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem.',
          'Nemo enim ipsam <i>voluptatem, quia voluptas sit, <b>aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, <u>sed quia</i> consequuntur</u> magni dolores eos</b>, qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt, neque porro quisquam est, qui do lorem ipsum, quia dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing velit, sed quia non numquam do eius modi tempora incididunt, ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem.'
          ],
         ['Ut enim ad minima veniam',
          'Ut enim ad minima veniam'],
         ['Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit',
          'Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit'],
         ['At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus, qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti, quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint, obcaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa, qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga.',
          'At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos<BR>ducimus, qui blanditiis praesentium<BR>voluptatum deleniti atque<BR>corrupti, quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint, obcaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa, qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga.'
         ]]
        for n_row, row in enumerate(rows):
            self.table_view.model().insertRow(n_row)
            self.table_view.model().setItem(n_row, 0, QtGui.QStandardItem(row[0]))
            self.table_view.model().setItem(n_row, 1, QtGui.QStandardItem(row[1]))
        self.table_view.setColumnWidth(0, 400)
        self.table_view.setColumnWidth(1, 400)
        
class HistoryTableView(QtWidgets.QTableView):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__(*args)
        self.setSelectionMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.SingleSelection)
        self.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)
        self.horizontalHeader().hide()
        self.verticalHeader().hide()
        self.setModel(HistoryTableModel(self))
        self.setItemDelegate(HistoryTableDelegate(self))
        v_header =  self.verticalHeader()
        v_header.setMinimumSectionSize(5)
        v_header.sectionHandleDoubleClicked.disconnect()
        v_header.sectionHandleDoubleClicked.connect(self.resizeRowToContents)
        self.horizontalHeader().sectionResized.connect(self.resizeRowsToContents)   
        
    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        print(f'{get_time()}: QTV resizeEvent')
        super().resizeEvent(event)
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0, self.resizeRowsToContents)
        
    def resizeRowsToContent(self):
        print(f'{get_time()}: QTV resizeRowsToContent')
        header = self.verticalHeader()
        for row in range(self.model().rowCount()):
            hint = self.sizeHintForRow(row)
            header.resizeSection(row, hint)    
            
class HistoryTableDelegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args):
        super().__init__(parent, *args)
        self.editor = None
    
    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        print(f'{get_time()}: Delegate createEditor')
        self.editor = EntryEdit(parent, self)
        self.editor_index = index
        self.row = index.row()
        return self.editor
    
    def editor_text_changed(self, *args):
        print(f'{get_time()}: Delegate editor_text_changed')
            
    def setModelData(self, editor, model, index):
        print(f'{get_time()}: Delegate setModelData')
        plain_text = self.editor.document().toPlainText()
        plain_text = plain_text.replace('\n', '<BR>')
        model.setData(index, plain_text, QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole)
            
    def destroyEditor(self, editor, index):
        print(f'{get_time()}: Delegate destroyEditor')
        super().destroyEditor(editor, index)
        self.parent().resizeRowToContents(index.row())
        self.editor = None           
        
    def sizeHint(self, option, index):
        print(f'{get_time()}: Delegate sizeHint')
        self.initStyleOption(option, index)
        if self.editor != None and self.editor_index == index:
            doc = self.editor.document()
        else:    
            doc = QtGui.QTextDocument()
            doc.setTextWidth(option.rect.width())
            doc.setDefaultFont(option.font)
            doc.setDocumentMargin(0)
            doc.setHtml(option.text)
        return QtCore.QSize(int(doc.idealWidth()), int(doc.size().height()))
    
    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        print(f'{get_time()}: Delegate paint')
        self.initStyleOption(option, index)
        painter.save()
        if self.editor != None and self.editor_index == index:
            doc = self.editor.document()
        else:
            doc = QtGui.QTextDocument()
            doc.setDocumentMargin(0)
            doc.setDefaultFont(option.font)
            doc.setTextWidth(option.rect.width())
            doc.setHtml(option.text)
        option.text = ""
        option.widget.style().drawControl(QtWidgets.QStyle.CE_ItemViewItem, option, painter)
        painter.translate(option.rect.left(), option.rect.top())
        doc.drawContents(painter)
        painter.restore()
        
class HistoryTableModel(QtGui.QStandardItemModel):
    def appendRow(self, *args):
        super().appendRow(*args)
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0, self.parent().resizeRowsToContents)
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(10, self.parent().scrollToBottom)
        
    def data(self, index, role):
        if role == QtCore.Qt.TextAlignmentRole:
            return QtCore.Qt.AlignTop
        return super().data(index, role)
    
class EntryEdit(QtWidgets.QTextEdit):
    def __init__(self, parent, delegate, *args):
        assert isinstance(delegate, QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate)
        super().__init__(parent, *args)
        self.delegate = delegate
        self.setSizeAdjustPolicy(QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit.SizeAdjustPolicy.AdjustToContents)
        self.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.setFrameShape(0)
        editor_document = EditorDocument(self)
        self.setDocument(editor_document)
        # put the cursor to the end of the EntryEdit at start of edit...
        self.textChanged.connect(delegate.editor_text_changed)
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0, self.cursor_to_end)
    
    def cursor_to_end(self):
        print(f'{get_time()}: Editor cursor_to_end')
        new_cursor = self.textCursor()
        new_cursor.movePosition(QtGui.QTextCursor.End)
        self.setTextCursor(new_cursor)
        
    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        # Ctrl+Return to end an edit session (keeping modified contents)
        if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key.Key_Enter or event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key.Key_Return:
            modifs = QtWidgets.QApplication.keyboardModifiers()
            if modifs == QtCore.Qt.ControlModifier:
                self.delegate.commitData.emit(self)
                self.delegate.closeEditor.emit(self)
        super().keyPressEvent(event)
        self.delegate.parent().resizeRowsToContents()

class EditorDocument(QtGui.QTextDocument):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setDocumentMargin(0)
        self.contentsChanged.connect(self.contents_changed)
        parent.setDocument(self)

    def contents_changed(self, *args):
        print(f'{get_time()}: Document contents_changed')
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0, self.resize_editor)

    def resize_editor(self, *args):
        print(f'{get_time()}: Document resize_editor')
        doc_size = self.size()
        self.parent().resize(int(doc_size.width()), int(doc_size.height()))
                
app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
main_window = MainWindow()
main_window.show()
exec_return = app.exec()
sys.exit(exec_return)
```

The thing to do is double-click in the bottom right cell (or press F2). Then add some lines to the bottom of the text. You will see that the text cursor disappears from view, but type a couple more lines.

Then press Ctrl-Return: this has been set up to end the editing session, saving the contents.

Then single-click in the cell above... and then in the bottom right cell again. After a fraction of a second this cell triggers the scrolling properly so that all its contents can be seen.

My goal: to ensure that, during editing, the text cursor does not disappear from view. I.e. that whatever mechanism caused that correct display when the focus goes away and comes back again, is invoked appropriately, probably on detecting that the `QTextCursor` is "out of sight".

My observations are that by doing this focus away and back again, the only `print` statement of the ones I've included that gets called is the one in the delegate's `paint` method. I surmise that the problem is that something is not getting the right "size hint" at the right time during editing. But I can't work out what to do.

In a Java context I'd be wondering about "invalidating" the cell: painting in Swing seemed to be a consequence of a part of screen real estate becoming "invalid". I don't know what triggers `sizeHint` and/or `paint` in Qt.

Comment: Truth is, editors should *never* change the size of their cell, unless really required (for instance, a complex editor that requires a minimum size to show its contents). If you look at the behavior of the standard editor, it only resizes the editor geometry, *not* that of its index. That's for various (and good) reasons: for instance, if you remove a couple of lines, you'll see the current (unedited) data *under* the editor; if the editor is then rejected, you'll probably get some "ghost painting" of the previous content caused by the fact that the row has been resized.

Comment: Yes, it does ghost, as I can clearly see the current text of the item whenever I remove lines above the bottom edge of the index, and if the index holds the minimum height for the row and lines are removed from it, rejecting the contents doesn't properly update the view. The editor should not (note, I specifically used "should", not "must") dynamically resize the item because it could create problems that are difficult to solve, exactly like yours: in this case, the only way to properly show the resized item would be to show the vertical scroll bar of the view, but that would cause a problem->

Comment: Thanks, but I don't agree. Firstly, this is an MRE. In my real app, using the `QTextDocument` from the editor in `paint` (as with `sizeHint`) actually solves most "ghosting" issues (will now change). Secondly I think this in-place editor within a table cell is a perfectly reasonable thing to want to implement, and a real-world implementation must mean that the text cursor doesn't just disappear in these circumstances.

Comment: ->as the item would be also resized in its width, which would probably cause another resize in the item to allow a further line if the current width doesn't suffice. Then you'll also need to ensure that the item rect becomes effectly visible, but what if the editor requires a geometry that is taller than the viewport? That's a limit you cannot directly (nor easily) know, and there's again no easy way to ensure that the cursor remains visible since you're dealing with two nested scroll areas. And this is not even considering the effect in case the model is very big. As said, the proper ->

Comment: -> (and simpler) solution, which is also what most view system do (including Qt), is to just adapt the editor geometry in order to take advantage of the available size, and then just allow vertical scrolling using the cursor navigation.

Comment: If I understand what you're recommending, you are saying allow the vertical scrollbar in the `QTextEdit`. I did that to begin with (a simple solution, as you say), but this inevitably starts off (when you insert a new, empty row) with a one-line `QTextEdit`, with a scrollbar, which is horrible. The next step is to decide to impose an arbitrary minimum height on the editor, etc. But in truth my solution here seems to work pretty well... APART from the disappearing cursor (which only happens when the table is already occupying a lot of the viewport). Identifying whether the cursor is ->

Comment: -> visible is indeed a big part of the puzzle. In Swing I seem to recall that even within multiple nested scrolling viewports there was a function "is object visible"! But that is only the secondary part of the problem. The main one is: how to provoke a `paint` in mid-edit?

Comment: Why do you want to "provoke a paint", and what would change in your problem? In any case, if the issue was about the empty state, then it's just about setting the proper initial geometry.

Comment: I just tried to move this discussion to chat ... but it failed. Can you spare a couple of minutes to discuss things?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244758/discussion-between-musicamante-and-mike-rodent).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Musicamante explained to me in a discussion that the most relevant method for my purposes is `QTableView.scrollTo()`. Using that tip I changed the delegate's method `editor_text_changed` to the following:

```
def editor_text_changed(self, *args):
    print(f'{get_time()}: Delegate editor_text_changed')
    def scroll():
        self.parent().scrollTo(self.editor_index)
    QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(10, scroll)
```

or, more concisely:

```
def editor_text_changed(self, *args):
    print(f'{get_time()}: Delegate editor_text_changed')
    QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(10, lambda: self.parent().scrollTo(self.editor_index))
```

... putting a non-zero ms value here seems to do the trick in a non-intermittent way.

Musicamante clearly thinks that my approach (where essentially I'm trying to make the user have the illusion that the rendered cell has magically become an editor when an edit session starts) is fundamentally undesirable. As long as I can overcome the technical hitches which he foresees I'm quite happy to persist with my illusion-based approach.

I think making things so that the editor starts to eat up (i.e. mask) other parts of the table (rows above in his solution) is not particularly desirable.

From a purely practical/ergonomics standpoint, supposing the user needs to make reference to the content of the preceding rows whilst editing the final row? In my example, indeed, as the class names might suggest (forget the "Lorem ipsum"...!), this is a chronological "history" consisting of dated "entries", so the user is very likely to need to be able to see the previous entries' contents.

Answer (score 0):

The editor should normally not try to change the size of the view items. This is a standard behavior across many toolkits, and is the same behavior for the default editor in Qt too.

A better and simpler solution is to adapt the geometry of the editor based on its contents changes, and ensure that it always has the correct position and *never* exceeds the viewport visible area.

```py
class HistoryTableDelegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args):
        super().__init__(parent, *args)
        self.editor = None
    
    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        self.editor = EntryEdit(parent, index)
        self.editor.setMinimumHeight(option.rect.height() + 
            self.editor.frameWidth() * 2)
        self.editor.commit.connect(self.commitData)
        self.editor.commit.connect(self.closeEditor)
        self.editor.updateSizeRequest.connect(self.updateEditorSize)
        self.editor_index = index
        self.row = index.row()
        return self.editor

    def updateEditorSize(self, editor, index):
        geo = self.parent().visualRect(index)
        docHeight = int(editor.document().size().height())
        height = max(editor.minimumHeight(), 
            docHeight + editor.frameWidth() * 2)
        geo.setHeight(height)
        parentGeo = editor.parent().rect()
        if geo.bottom() > parentGeo.bottom():
            geo.moveBottom(parentGeo.bottom())
        if geo.y() < 0:
            geo.setTop(0)
        editor.setGeometry(geo)

    def updateEditorGeometry(self, editor, opt, index):
        b = editor.frameWidth()
        editor.setGeometry(opt.rect.adjusted(-b, -b, b, b))

    # ...


class EntryEdit(QtWidgets.QTextEdit):
    updateSizeRequest = QtCore.pyqtSignal(object, QtCore.QModelIndex)
    commit = QtCore.pyqtSignal(QtWidgets.QWidget, 
        QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate.EndEditHint)
    def __init__(self, parent, index):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.index = index
        self.setFrameShape(0)
        # a small border to ensure that the rectangle of the editor 
        # is always visible when it exceeds the size of its index
        self.setStyleSheet('''
            EntryEdit {
                border: 1px solid lightGray;
            }
        ''')
        self.document().setDocumentMargin(0)
        self.updateSizeTimer = QtCore.QTimer(self, singleShot=True, 
            interval=0, timeout=self.emitUpdateSize)
        self.document().contentsChanged.connect(self.updateSizeTimer.start)

    def emitUpdateSize(self):
        self.updateSizeRequest.emit(self, self.index)

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if (event.key() in (QtCore.Qt.Key_Enter, QtCore.Qt.Key_Return) 
            and event.modifiers() == QtCore.Qt.ControlModifier):
                self.commit.emit(self, QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate.NoHint)
                return
        super().keyPressEvent(event)
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried this out. I think possibly you might want to add a (possibly deferred) `scrollTo` in `destroyEditor` (following your explanation to me about `scrollTo`) because at the moment in my system after the edit session ends the bottom part of the newly edited cell is not visible. Apart from that I think I want to persist with an editor which gives the user the illusion that the "cell has magically become an editor", and thanks to your explanation to me in the discussion about `scrollTo` I seem to have found a fairly painless way of accomplishing that.